# Efficiently showing Access data in C#

Tags: c#, ms-access

I've been learning about obtaining and modifying access data in C# for a few days and I have a pretty good idea on how to do it.

What I find a bit hard to understand is how to efficiently show data in **A windows form**.

My access table is information on a Supplier, and it has 11 fields in it (name, street etc)

Now I want to be able to have users see all this data as well as modify it in C#.

So far I have tried just having 11 text boxes with corresponding list boxes as well, and the list boxes contained a specific field and when you clicked on any of them, all the data would go into the text box which could be modified.

However I found that this is ridiculously inefficient as I was changing the value of listboxes/Textboxes constantly.

is there a way to efficiently show all the data in a Table? (even if it has many fields, IE upwards of 15), or should I look at an alternative solution.

Thank you.

Comment: Is this WinForms or web application?

Comment: This is a windows form. I'll edit that info in thanks.

Comment: Use a `DataGridView`?

Comment: Data Binding is what you want to be looking at. If you look at how to do more basic stuff, such as a ListBox or a Grid, you'll get there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `DataGridView` control.

Read [C# DataGridView tutorial](http://www.dotnetperls.com/datagridview-tutorial).

Comment: Thank you, I will use this.